# get lat lon value from basemap while mouse hover and showing them to textctrl

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, matplotlib-basemap

i'm having problem on getting lat lon value when mouse over basemap. my intention is getting those lat lon value (just like coordinate that showing at the right bottom of matplotlib window plot.show()) and put them to text control or static text which in another panel.

i'm banging my head for this. i'm a newbie in matplotlib and wxpython so please help.